# How to intercept Websockets, Server Sent Events (SSE) and ReadableStream Request and Response in Angular?

Tags: angular, fetch-api, angular-httpclient, angular-httpclient-interceptors

I want stream real time data from server to client. We are using Angular 16. I want to intercept the Request and Response of WebSockets, Server Sent Events (SSE) and ReadableStream using **Angular Interceptor**.
Is any one implemented?

Does any one used Angular HttpClientModule and Http interceptor in following HTML5 API's **SSE API**, **WebSockets** or **Fetch API**.
I want to stream the real time data from server to client. I implemented one fetch API in the project but that request is not happening through Angular Interceptor. Because Http client module not having the **fetch** Method. Is anyone extend or override the Angular Client module or Http interceptor?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to intercept Websockets or Server Send Events with HttpInterceptors. I think you have to implement something by yourself.

1. For SSE you can create a custom wrapper of [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) that fit your needs.
2. For intercepting Websocket send and received messages, i think the only way is to monkey-patch the Websocket-Class